# git version update is not reflecting

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am trying to update git on one of my Ubuntu server and I ran the below commands to update that.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa

sudo apt-get install git
```

I got my version updated to /usr/bin but not in /usr/local/bin

```
user@host:~$ /usr/bin/git --version
git version 2.32.0

user@host:~$ /usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 2.13.0
```

I read few suggestion to change the sequence of the directories in PATH variable, but I am afraid that might break something else. Is there another way to fix it?

why git was not updated in /usr/local/bin by default?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/bin/git` was installed by `apt`, so it was upgraded by `apt`.

`/usr/local/bin/git` was not installed by `apt`. And because of that, `apt` knows nothing about it. Even if `apt` knew about it, it wouldn't be safe to it to touch it, because it wasn't installed by `apt`. This is why it was not upgraded by `apt`.

What you should do:

1. Delete `/usr/local/bin/git` (and related files, such as man pages).
2. Make `/usr/local/bin/git` a symlink to `/usr/bin/git`.

The second step is optional. It will help if a program uses the full path `/usr/local/bin/git` instead of just `git`. If all programs merely use `git`, they will find `/usr/bin/git` (via the PATH) once you've deleted `/usr/local/bin/git`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the installation in `local` seems to be a *custom* installation (perhaps from sources?) and it's more than likely that apt doesn't know about it (as in *it was not made by apt*).

Then, the question about PATH, feel free to modify PATH on your **current** terminal like this (no other sessions will be affected):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH
```

Then, if you like how it behaves (like the git that runs is the one from there), you can consider keeping it as part of your setup in `~/.bash_profile` so that it is set up whenever you start a new bash session (by the way.... doing this has security implications as you will be checking for binaries/scripts first in a location that *might* be easier to hack than the base system). If you don't like it, then just close that bash session and it's like it never happened.

Another possibility is to use an alias for `git` that uses the one in local. Then there is no need to modify PATH.

Comment: Isn't that backwards? They probably want the install they just upgraded, which isn't `/usr/local/bin/`. But before you suggest `/usr/bin` before `/usr/local/bin`, that would be a bad idea.

Comment: @ikegami Good call on bash_profile. Thanks. About the other comment: I agree but.... if they want to use the one in local first in PATH, so be it.

Comment: I was editing the comment to talk about possible side effects while you were writing about it too. Thanks for bringing it up, just in case.

Comment: Thanks, I need to enable the new version for all the users or sessions without exporting path variable explicitly each time

Comment: Then you should forget about the one in local and let apt take care of the one in the base system.... unless you mean it and you know what you are doing.

Comment: whats the way to change in /usr/local/bin

Comment: how to let apt take care of this

Comment: It depends on the way it was installed... which is probably not through apt and we can't tell just like that. You might need to specify more details about how git showed up there in local in the first place

Comment: Latest is 2.32.0 so the one in the base system is already updated to the latest (which is normally done with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, just in case)